# Specifying precompressed (gzip) vs non-precompressed content in IIS7 by filetype

Tags: iis-7, gzip

I am trying to essentially setup an IIS7 intranet CDN for a series of nested folders containing some precompressed (gzip) css content but also image files (obviously noncompressed).

The folder structure is essentially something like this:

```
Skins
Skins\SkinName1\*.css
Skins\SkinName1\Control1\*.png
Skins\SkinName1\Control2\*.png
Skins\SkinName1\lots more controls..\*.png
Skins\SkinName2\...
Skins\lots more skins...\...
```

..you get the idea..

The css is all pre-compressed (gzip'ed) so I need to set a Content-Encoding header of 'gzip' on them..  but I obviously can't set the same header on the image files.

I know I could set the Content-Encoding gzip folder at the root, and then not-inherit it on all the Control (image) folders.. but there's a ton of image folders to have to go through.

Is there any way to set this by file type or something that would keep from having to go through each folder individually?

*Unfortunately I don't have any control over the folder structure.

Thanks-

Comment: Won't this scheme fail if the client doesn't support `gzip` for whatever reason?

Comment: @EricLaw Fair point.  I guess you really should consider checking the Accept-Encoding header first before assuming, but from what I remember I think pretty much all browsers have supported it for years.  In my particular scenario it was for an intranet CDN so I was safe to assume it was one of a couple of different enterprise-standard modern browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I finally realized I should be using the URL Rewrite module and let it add the custom header.

I basically just used this:

```
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Set custom HTTP response header" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content_Encoding" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.css$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip"/>
        </rule> 
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

and let the non-precompressed stuff default as it should.

hope it helps someone-

Comment: Yup, precisely what I was looking for. I kept going between automatic compression or no Content-Encoding for so long it drove me partially insane, and then I found this!

Comment: Where do I put that configuration?

Comment: And, What makes the IIS server precompress the files?